# Azure policy with "Modify" effect not working

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I have an Azure policy with a "Modify" effect:

```json
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Web/sites"
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Web/sites/publicNetworkAccess",
          "exists": "false"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "[parameters('effect')]",
      "details": {
        "roleDefinitionIds": [
          "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c"
        ],
        "operations": [
          {
            "condition": "[greaterOrEquals(requestContext().apiVersion, '2022-09-01')]",
            "operation": "addOrReplace",
            "field": "Microsoft.Web/sites/publicNetworkAccess",
            "value": "Disabled"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "effect": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Effect",
        "description": "Enable or disable the execution of the policy"
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        "Modify",
        "Disabled"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "Modify"
    }
  }
}
```

As I understand, this policy will set the attribute "publicNetworkAccess" of resource "Microsoft.Web/sites" to false if the attribute does not exist

After assigning the policy to my only subscription, I used ARM template to deploy the "Microsoft.Web/sites" resources:

```json
{
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
            "name": "[parameters('webAppName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanPortalName'))]"
            ],
            "identity": {
                "type": "SystemAssigned"
            },
            "properties": {
                "httpsOnly": true,
                "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanPortalName'))]",
                "siteConfig": {
                    "linuxFxVersion": "[parameters('linuxFxVersion')]",
                    "minTlsVersion": "1.2",
                    "ftpsState": "FtpsOnly"
                }
            }
        }
```

However, after the deployment is completed, I check the app service and see that the "publicNetworkAccess" is set to "Enabled":
[image]

It means that the policy does not take effect. What's wrong with my policy ?

Comment: From documentation [of properties for microsoft.web/sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#property-values) it seems that `publicNetworkAccess` accept as values only empty string, `Enabled` and `Disabled`, the value `Modify` is not listed here.

Comment: Take a look at the remediation task, maybe the assigned identy does not have sufficient permissions.

Comment: These comments are somehow misleading. @RobertoFerraris `Modify` is the effect, not the value. The `allowedValues` are for the effect-parameter, meaning what happens once the `policyRule` evaluates to true

Comment: @PeterBons the permissions used for the `managed identity` equals `Contributor`, which is more than sufficient:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor ... look for `b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c`

Comment: @Niclas assuming a system assigned managed identity is used that would be correct. I mainly use user assigned managed identitities. Using uai can lead to misconfigurations.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `policyRule` to include `anyOf` like this (this is best practice):

```
"policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Web/sites"
          },
          {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Web/sites/publicNetworkAccess",
                "exists": "false"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Web/sites/publicNetworkAccess",
                "notEquals": "Disabled"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
```

For sake of learning, then use PS this to check if the property is modifiable:

```
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId <subid>
Get-AzPolicyAlias -NamespaceMatch Microsoft.Web | where ResourceType -like 'sites*' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Aliases | Where-Object { $_.DefaultMetadata.Attributes -eq 'Modifiable' } | where name -like '*public*' | Select Name,DefaultPath
```

Remember that the `policyRule` only proceed if the condition is evaluated as 'true'.

```
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Web/sites/publicNetworkAccess",
                "exists": "false"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Web/sites/publicNetworkAccess",
                "notEquals": "Disabled"
              }
            ]
```

By default, the `web app` will have this value `"publicNetworkAccess": null`, which means that the above `if`-statement is true.

`Reason for non-compliance: Current value must exist.`
Now the policy is ready for remediation.

You are using `Contributor` as permissions for the (system assigned) `managed identity`, this is overprivileged, but will of course worked.

To follow the process, you can run this to get all the properties of your web app BEFORE the `remediation`:

```
$webapp = Get-AzResource -Name <WEBAPPNAME> -ResourceGroupName <RG-NAME> -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites
```

`$webapp` it is empty. You can also confirm by running this:

```
$webapp.Properties.publicNetworkAccess
```

Now run your policy remediation, once completed, repeat the `$webapp = Get-AzResource`-command steps to refresh the variable.

Answer (score 0):

> However, after the deployment is completed, I check the app service and see that the "publicNetworkAccess" is set to "Enabled":

Here is the updated `Azure Policy` to **disable** the `publicNetworkAccess` property for `Azure Web Apps` (`Microsoft.Web/sites`) only if it is already `enabled`.

> Note: Make sure you have role assignment access, such as the Owner role, and also wait for some time for the process to update.

```json
    {
      "mode": "All",
      "policyRule": {
        "if": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "type",
              "equals": "Microsoft.Web/sites"
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Web/sites/publicNetworkAccess",
              "equals": "Enabled"
            }
          ]
        },
        "then": {
          "effect": "[parameters('effect')]",
          "details": {
            "roleDefinitionIds": [
              "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c"
            ],
            "operations": [
              {
                "operation": "addOrReplace",
                "field": "Microsoft.Web/sites/publicNetworkAccess",
                "value": "Disabled"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "parameters": {
        "effect": {
          "type": "String",
          "metadata": {
            "displayName": "Effect",
            "description": "Enable or disable the execution of the policy"
          },
          "allowedValues": [
            "Modify",
            "Disabled"
          ],
          "defaultValue": "Modify"
        }
      }
    }
```

While assigning the policy, make sure to **enable** the `remediation task` to implement changes as follows.

[image]

The policy has been updated to **disable** public access for web apps.

[image]

[image]

The public access for the web app has been set to **disabled**.

[image]